Piping output to bash script
I'm going through the "sed & awk" book by Dougherty and Robbins.  One of the examples calls for piping output to a shell script:
sed -f nameState list | byState

But I've found that, in order to work, I have to give the 'byState' script execute permissions with chmod as well as call it with the dot-slash:
sed -f nameState list | ./byState

Is this always to be the case?  The book hails from 1997, so maybe the shell standard has changed?  Or it's because I'm using bash and not sh?
EDIT: Here's the byState script:
#! /bin/sh
awk -F, ’{
        print $4 ", " $0
        }’ $* |
sort |
awk -F, ’
$1 == LastState {
      print "\t" $2
}
$1 != LastState {
      LastState = $1
      print $1
      print "\t" $2
}’


Add details please, what is that byState script supposed to do and stuff. Thanks

This has nothing to do with the pipe, really, just running the script. It's possible to include . (the current directory) in the shell's PATH, which would allow running a program file in the current directory without the explicit ./. But doing that is considered a bad and unsafe habit. I don't know if there has been a system where the execute bit wouldn't be needed for scripts, but I suppose it's possible the book just skimmed over that part as being obvious?

if you wish to execute the script you can also preface the name with your shell, eg, sed ... | bash byState); another option that may work (depends on the content of the script) would be to source the script, eg, sed ... | . byState or sed ... | source byState; the leading period is needed when the script has been granted execute permission and the current directory (.) is not listed in the environment variable PATH

byState script added to post

@markp-fuso  Prefacing with the shell did work, even without using './'

Way back it used to be common practice to include the current directory in one's $PATH. These days it's seen as a security risk. The book hails from the end of the earlier more innocent times

Executing a command name that doesn't contain a / is intended for commands that are to be looked up in one of the directories listed in $PATH¹. You wouldn't want rm file to run the rm command that happens to be in the current working directory instead of the standard rm².
If you want to run the byState executable that is found in a particular directory, as opposed to the first one (if any) found in any of the $PATH directories, you need to invoke it by its path. As that has to contain at least one /, for the one that is in the current working directory, you typically use ./byState which, like byState is a relative path to that file, but is one that contains a /. You could also use /full/path/to/byState or ././byState or ../here/byState which would also work.
If you want that byState script to be executable as just byState by anyone on the system regardless of their working directory, you can ask the system administrator to put a copy of it in /usr/local/bin (or any directory that is in the default $PATH though /usr/local/bin is the place intended for locally installed commands). Or you could even make a software package for it (like a .deb file if for a Debian-based system) including that executable and its man page for instance and which would list its dependencies (sh, awk, sort though those are essential software that will always be installed and don't need listed as a dependency) and ask the administrator to install it (like with gdebi/apt/dpkg on Debian-based systems), and then that could be put in /usr/bin. That would make it cleaner as it would be listed as an installed software with information about its maintainer, where the corresponding files are, and make it easier to uninstall.
If that byState is only for you, you can add it to one of your own directories and add that directory to your $PATH environment variables. Typical directories for that are ~/bin or ~/.local/bin.
In any case, to be able to execute a file, obviously you need to have execute permission on it. For scripts, you also need the file to have read permission as the interpreter (here /bin/sh) needs to be able to read the code in it to execute it.
chmod a+rx byState

Would give everyone (all) read and execute permission to it. Or you could specify the permissions in full with:
chmod a=rx,u+w byState

Which gives read+execute to all, and also write permission to the owner. Or chmod 755 byState with the octal form.
Now a few issues with your sh script (not a bash script, though bash would be able to interpret it would you ask it by changing the shebang to #! /path/to/bash - as its language has a compatible syntax):
Maybe a copy-paste issue, but those ’ are the wrong quotation marks, those are U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK. The quotation marks that shells recognise as strong quote operators are ', U+0027 APOSTROPHE.
$* unquoted in list context makes no sense whatsoever³. $* only makes sense when quoted but that's to join the positional parameters with the first character of $IFS4 which is not what you want here. To pass all the positional parameters verbatim to awk, you need "$@" (which must be quoted).
awk has that problem in that if you pass a filename such as foo=bar.txt, it's taken as an awk variable assignment instead. So here, you'd be better of doing5:
cat -- "$@" | awk ...

With print $4 ", " $0, you're adding a space in addition to the ,, so when on that output you do, print "\t" $2, that will print a tab, space and the field. Likely you want the input field separator (FS as set by -F) and output field separator (OFS) to both be just ,.
In $1 == LastState, beware that awk will do a numeric comparison if the operands look like numbers and string comparison6 otherwise. For instance it would say that 100, 1e2 and 100.0 are identical. If you want to make sure a string comparison is performed, you'd do $1 "" == LastState, or upon assigning LastState, make it LastState = $1 "" so it records the fact that it's a string and not potentially a number.
Rather than checking for equality twice, with LastState = $1 and LastState != $1, you could add a next at the end of the action for the first check to skip having to compare again, or use a if/else statement in an action run unconditionally.
sort is very well capable of sorting input based on the 4th field7, you don't have to move it to the front.
#! /bin/sh -
sort -t, -k4,4 -- "$@" |
  LC_ALL=C awk -F, '
    {
      if ($4 == LastState)
        print "\t" $1
      else {
        LastState = $4
        print $4 ORS "\t" $1
      }
    }'

Or factorising the print "\t" $1 and making it more legible / straightforward:
#! /bin/sh -
sort -t, -k4,4 -- "$@" |
  LC_ALL=C awk -F, '
    $4 != LastState {print LastState = $4}
    {print "\t" $1}'


¹ For those that are not otherwise a shell builtin command or function or alias (when literal and unquoted) of one of the keywords in the shell syntax such as while, for... (also when literal and unquoted).
² Decades ago, it was not uncommon to include . or the empty string, both of which mean the current working directory in $PATH, even at the front (!) where you would run into this kind of problem, but nobody would be foolish enough to do it these days.
³ Basically, that's asking the shell to join the positional parameters (the arguments to the script) with the first character of $IFS4 and then (because of the missing quotes), to split the result again on any character of $IFS and to subject each resulting word to globbing aka filename generation aka pathname expansion. That $* would make sense in the rc shell, the once to be successor of the Bourne shell, though that unfortunately never happened, but you'd need a #! /bin/rc shebang, or zsh where $* expands to the non-empty positional parameters when not running in sh/ksh emulation.
4 With the Bourne shell, a pre-POSIX shell that was still found as /bin/sh on some systems in 1997, that would join them with space instead regardless of the value of $IFS.
5 cat doesn't have those problems, but (and that also applies to sort and awk) treat - as meaning standard input, so if you have a file called -, you have to pass it as ./ or any other path to it to work around that.
6 With many awk implementations, that's not even a byte-to-byte string comparison, but whether the two strings sort the same. Running awk in the C locale would make sure that's a string comparison.
7 The -k start,end[flag] syntax is the new (as in early 90s, maybe late 80s) syntax, it's possible that in 1997, there were still sort implementations that didn't support it and only the ancient now long-obsoleted +offset syntax, which might explain why they didn't use it.

Yes.  If you are going to call the script like that, it needs to be marked executable (and ideally have a shbang).  This is not a new thing.
Your term "dot-slash", is simply specifying the path to the script, the single dot representing the current directory.  As pointed out by @ilkachu, is is a security issue to include "dot" in your path, this would lead to whatever directory that might be $CWD at the moment appearing in your search path.
